# Is it possible to use python as a shell replacement?

Tags: python, shell, bash

Recently I was looking at python's `shutil` and `subprocess` etc... And I started wondering: wouldn't it be ok to use python instead of e.g. bash?

What am I missing?

Comment: You can replace bash with iPython I believe [http://ipython.org/](http://ipython.org/)

Comment: See also [Object-oriented shell for *nix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4495/object-oriented-shell-for-nix)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Convenience of syntax, mostly.

In python, running a process requires `subprocess.call(...)`; renaming a file `shutil.move()`, etc. Bash syntax is much more direct for those tasks.

Yes, Python is a great language, but the explicit syntax to execute (for bash) simple tasks is going to get in the way of doing day-to-day work real fast.

Comment: http://amoffat.github.com/sh/

Comment: @isbadawi: exactly; adding a powerful module helps improve the convience levels of course! But if we are looking at *just* python, then those same tasks are going to be (a lot) more cumbersome.

Comment: Looking just at "just python" (which I presume is core language + stdlib to you) is useless IMHO, in that it doesn't match how the language is actually used.

Comment: @delnan: sure, but it is a major reason why we are not all using Python as our default shell, I'd say.

Comment: @isbadawi Even with that package, it's still rather verbose/cluttered compared to bash...

Comment: @Izkata: verbose/cluttered is a relative thing. I find doing almost *any* type of serious programming in bash to be like getting a root canal without anesthesia. (And I say that having been at a shell prompt since 1980.) Bash still is forking subprocesses just like Python, so it doesn't seem to have any inherent advantage other than 3 decades of inertia.

Comment: Also see [Why are scripting languages (e.g. Perl, Python, Ruby) not suitable as shell languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3640403/2988) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Here's the latest Internet Archive of this question: [Why are scripting languages (e.g. Perl, Python, Ruby) not suitable as shell languages?](https://web.archive.org/web/20140528035940/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637668/why-are-scripting-languages-e-g-perl-python-ruby-not-suitable-as-shell-lang)